# Confusion about proof of matrix derivative

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand why $\nabla_x (x^tAx)=2Ax$ when $A$ is symmetric.

In other words, I am trying to find $$\nabla_x (x^tAx)=\frac{\delta}{\delta x_k}\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_i x_j.$$ I am reading a proof of this, and everything makes sense except for why it is that $$\frac{\delta}{\delta x_k}\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} x_i x_j=\frac{\delta}{\delta x_k}(\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ik} x_i x_k+\sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj} x_k x_j).$$

Could someone please help me understand why this step above is valid and how we know this? Thanks.

Comment: What is $j$ in the first sum of your final result?

Comment: I mean in the second equation right side, there is a sum on the $i$ but a $j$ is present in there too

Comment: @MattiaMariantoni Sorry haha, I fixed it now. Thanks for correction.

Comment: It's confusing because splitting the double sums is not correct until after the derivative operator is applied.

Comment: @arthur I see thanks a lot, this makes sense why I couldn't understand before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two derivatives are equivalent because only terms that do not contain $x_{k}$ are eliminated from the second expression

Comment: Break the summations on the left in $i,j$ that both do not contain contain the value $k$ plus all the remaining terms that have at least one $k$ present. Only the latter terms will remain and that is the RHS